# Several root nodes unwrapping using Jackson without using wrapper classes

Tags: java, json, jackson

All the answers on stackoverflow regarding Jackson I found deal with only single root node unwrapping for JSONs like

```
{
  "user":
    {
      "name":"Sam Smith",
      "age":1
    }
}
```

The solution is to either use wrapper classes or use .withRootName("user") call like this

```
User user = objectMapper.reader()
                .forType(User.class)
                .withRootName("user")
                .readValue(string);
```

also annotating User class with`@JsonRootName(value = "user")` is the option.

But is there an option to NOT use wrapper classes for JSONs with several parallel root nodes like this:

```
{
  "user":
    {
      "name":"Sam Smith",
      "age":1
    },
  "timestamp":
    {
      "clickpoint":"AE12",
      "purchasable":"false"
    }
}
```

. Can't find a solution for that. Jackson will throw an exception of not matching root name "timestamp" with expected "user". Thank you for help if you know the answer.

Comment: The 2nd JSON in your question is not valid. Can you [double-check it](https://jsonlint.com/)?

Comment: Thank you, I corrected that - missed a comma and a quote mark. Doesn't change my question

Answer (score 0):

To operate with objects without named root you can deal with JsonNode like in the example below:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode node = mapper.reader().readTree(source);

    User user = mapper.treeToValue(node.get("user"), User.class);
    Timestamp timestamp = mapper.treeToValue(node.get("timestamp"), Timestamp.class);

    System.out.println(user.getName());
    System.out.println(timestamp.getClickpoint());
```

In older version of Jackson instead of `treeToValue()` you can use `readValue()` with the same arguments.